# tkinter Text <Destroy> event comes too late

Tags: tkinter, widget, bind

I have a script that uses the Text widget to edit text files.
When the window is closing ( 'close' icon clicked) I want to check if an amended file is unsaved.

I have bound the Destroy event

```
`self.bind('<Destroy>', self.end_act)`
```

but end_act() fails with

```
`_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!textwidget"`
```

indicating that the widget is already closed.

Is there any other event that will achieve this result ?

Comment: format your code and error properly

Comment: also, post a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Use `self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", ...)` instead:

```py
    self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)

...

def on_close(self):
    self.end_act() # execute the required function you want
    self.destroy() # then close the window
```

Comment: Thanks that was what I needed. Haven't used .protocol before